# add_blog_option blog ID

Tags: multisite, mysql

In multisite I run add_blog_option and look at the row in mysql wp_options. The record is there but I do not see a field for the blogID. How does the wp_options relate to the specific blog?

Answer (score 1):

In multisite each blog/site gets his own tables with the blog id in the prefix, so once you install a network installation your database should have these tables:

- wp_1_options
- wp_2_options